# 2 circles $C_1, C_2$ of radius $a$ and $b$ touch each other externally and they both touch a unit circle $C$ internally. Show $a+b=1$

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> 2 circles $C_1, C_2$ of radius $a$ and $b$ touch each other externally and they both touch a unit circle $C$ internally. A circle $C_3$ of radius $r$ is inscribed to touch the circles $C_1, C_2$ externally and the circle $C$ internally. Show that $r=\frac{ab}{1-ab}$.

The solution starts by saying $2a+2b=2$.
I am having a hard time understanding it.

Can someone explain it to me in simple terms? If possible please attach a diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be true if $C_1$ and $C_2$ had their centers on a diameter of $C$.  In the figure below the sum of the radii of circles $C$ and $E$ is much smaller than the radius of circle $A$

[image]